# Create relationship between custom post types and users

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, membership

How do I create a relationship between custom post types and registered users?
So, I can display posts related/associated with that user on their account page.
Please, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not set them as the author for the posts and then set the user as an author

Comment: I can't @rudtek. It is a membership site where uses are ascribed a basic membership upon registration.

Any other suggestion(s) please?

Comment: Create an additional relational  field (with acf or such) linked to a user, query posts by this new created field meta query